# Verilog Signed Multiplication of large values

Tags: cryptography, verilog, fpga

So I am working on DSA processor that must multiply large signed values to check if they fit onto a curve. The function I am using works in python given the same values, but when passed in Verilog I am getting incorrect results. I believe it has to deal with my signed values for y & x. During testbenching multiplying x or y by itself gave incorrect values.

```
module on_curve (
        input wire signed [511:0] point
);

reg signed [255:0] x, y;

always@*
begin
    x = point[511:256];
    y = point[255:0];

    if ((y * y - x * x * x - 0 * x - 7) % 256'hFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F == 0) begin
        $write("This value is on the curve");
    end

    if ((y * y - x * x * x - 0 * x - 7) % 256'hFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F !== 0) begin
        $write("This value is not on the curve");
    end
end
endmodule
```

The value i'm using for "point" is

```
512'h79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8;
```

which is the generator point for the DSA so it should fall onto the curve.

Comment: I edited the `'hFFFFF...` to be `256'hFFFFF...` to make reading easier. Mod isn't the problem atm. Even testing `y*y` in verilog yields a different result than `y*y` from python.

Comment: You haven't stated how `y*y` is different between Verilog and Python.  In my simulation `y*y` is `512'h1461286abe28c5f1df2d7d4bca391b5070f6ec678fe75b56871bf154841d1559c372d1541278bdcbe4f80e3d9e8b333f432bee128fd65b7c0ac2a7cc17c14440` and `x*x*x` is a 768-bit number.

Comment: Are you targeting this at SystemVerilog or are you wanting to implement this as a circuit? The multiplication operand works just fine in SystemVerilog, but is generally not usable for implementation. What IDE/simulator are you using? Can you provide simulation output?